# Create ISO File with .net DiscUtils

Tags: vb.net

I am working on an project that creates ISO files. Basically, all the files needed for the ISO is stored in a temporary directory and just needs to be saved to an ISO file.

I have tried the following code :

```
     Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim cdBuilder = New CDBuilder()
    cdBuilder.UseJoliet = True
    cdBuilder.VolumeIdentifier = TextBox1.Text
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        If SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "" Then

        Else

            For Each dr In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\TempISODir")

            Next
            cdBuilder.Build(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

but that just creates an empty folder like this "C: > Users > Adriaan > AppData > Local and so on. Does anyone have a good example on how to do this since I cannot make out anything from the help file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else that might come onto this with the same problem, this is how I solved the problem.

```
   Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim iso = New CDBuilder()
    iso.UseJoliet = True
    iso.VolumeIdentifier = TextBox1.Text
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        If SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "" Then

        Else
            Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\TempISODir")
            PopulateFromFolder(iso, di, di.FullName)
            iso.Build(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

    Private Shared Sub PopulateFromFolder(builder As CDBuilder, di As DirectoryInfo, basePath As String)
    For Each file As FileInfo In di.GetFiles()
        builder.AddFile(file.FullName.Substring(basePath.Length), file.FullName)
    Next

    For Each dir As DirectoryInfo In di.GetDirectories()
        PopulateFromFolder(builder, dir, basePath)
    Next
End Sub
```